# Projectile search only part of the project

Tags: emacs, projectile, emacs-helm

When using emacs [Projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile) and [helm-projectile](https://github.com/bbatsov/helm-projectile), I am used to search for text inside the whole project. However is there a way to search only part of the project?

Something like:

- search inside a subfolder only
- search while excluding a subfolder

Comment: I don't think searching inside a sub-folder is a proper use-case for projectile. Please consider using any generic library/package to do so e.g. silversearcher-ag/silversearcher-ag-el

Comment: @goromlagche could you post a link? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher#emacs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now I am using `rgrep`, which prompts for a string and a directory to find.

I would be happy to hear about an equivalent solution using `ag`, and I should mention I haven't yet dug into the link from @goromlagche (https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher#emacs).

Comment: Personally I didn't find `ack` or `ag` to be any better or faster than Emacs `rgrep` in practice. The most useful thing those other tools do is to automatically exclude files and directories that you wouldn't want to search, and `rgrep` does that too. So while they would be good on the command line, I found I had no reason to integrate them with Emacs.

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can [exclude (sub) folders](https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage/#ignoring-files). Add a line in your `.projectile`:

```
-/sub/folder
```

So search inside a subfolder, I don't see something automatic. You could put project files in some subfolders (https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#file-local-project-root-definitions) and [switch projects](https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#switching-projects).

Comment: That could be a workaround, however I need this kind of search only sporadically (and the reason I want this kind of search is to move files around in a big project into separate subfolders).

Answer (score 2):

Install `helm-ag`, this requires `silversearcher-ag` package; for debian `apt install silversearcher-ag`. And then you can

1. `helm-do-ag` to search inside a sub-folder/directory inside project
2. to ignore sub-folders/directories add them to either `.gitignore` or `.hgignore` if it is git and hg project respectively or add then to `.projectile` file, [details here](https://docs.projectile.mx/projectile/projects.html#ignoring-files).

references:

1. https://github.com/emacsorphanage/helm-ag
2. https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher